# Created structured/nested JSON from unstructured JSON

Tags: c#, performance, json, json.net

I have below `unstructured` but valid `JSON` which need to be converted to `structured` format using any `C# library` or `newtonsoft`-

```json
 {
    "root_id": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    },
    "root_tittel": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    },          
    "root_mottaker_adresse1": {
        "Path": "InsertDocuments",
        "MainContract": "CreateDocumentParameter"
    },
    "root_mottaker_adresse2": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    },
    "root_web_id_guid": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    }
}
```

**want to make it structured as below -**

```json
{
    "id": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    },
    "tittel": {
        "Path": "InsertCases",
        "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
    },              
    "mottaker": {
        "adresse1": {
            "Path": "InsertDocuments",
            "MainContract": "CreateDocumentParameter"
        },
        "adresse2": {
            "Path": "InsertCases",
            "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
        }
    },
    "web": {
        "id": {
            "guid": {
                "Path": "InsertCases",
                "MainContract": "CreateCaseParameter"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you see the difference the hierarchy is split with `_`(underscore). I want to make it in a more nested way.

i.e.

1. `root_element` -> `element`
2. `root_element1_element2` -> `element1` is parent and `element2` is child.

**Code**

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JObject finalObj = new JObject();
foreach (var item in obj)
{
    var keys = item.Key.Replace("root_", "").Split("_").Reverse();
    bool nestedKeyProcessed = false;
    JObject tempObj = new JObject();
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        if (keys.Count() > 1 && !nestedKeyProcessed)
        {
            tempObj = CreateJObject(key, item.Value);
            nestedKeyProcessed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (keys.Count() == 1)
                finalObj.Add(new JProperty(key, item.Value));
            else
                tempObj = CreateJObjectUsingJProperty(key, tempObj);
        }
    }
    if (keys.Count() > 1)
        finalObj.Merge(tempObj, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union });
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalObj);
JObject CreateJObject(string key, JToken? data)
{
    JObject obj = new JObject();
    obj.Add(key, data);
    return obj;
}
JObject CreateJObjectUsingJProperty(string key, object? data)
{
    JObject obj = new JObject(new JProperty(key, data));
    return obj;
}
```

Please review and let me know if it can be any optimized in any way

Comment: How large is your typical input json?

Comment: Welcome to Code review! What should be optimized? Speed, memory usage, time, readability? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ In all aspects if we can optimise it would be good enough!

Comment: @PeterCsala In what aspect the question is? Large as in?

Comment: Large in size (just a few bytes or several megabytes) or field count (no more than 10 flatten fields or more than a thousand fields)

Comment: @PeterCsala For now in bytes and not more that 50 flatten fields.

Comment: Thank you @PPB! One more question: How deep is the hierarchy after the deflattening? Like no more than 3 or it could be 10+?

Comment: @PeterCsala Utmost 5, not more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Let me present here an alternative solution

```
static readonly JsonMergeSettings MergeSettings = new() { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union };
const char LevelSeparator = '_';
static string DeflattenJson(string json)
{
    var mappings = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.Value);

    var objectsWithHierarchy = (from kv in mappings
        let entryLevels = kv.Key.Split(LevelSeparator).Skip(1).Reverse()
        let deflattened = CreateHierarchy(new Queue<string>(entryLevels.Skip(1)),
            new JObject(new JProperty(entryLevels.First(), kv.Value)))
        select deflattened).ToList();

    var baseObject = new JObject();
    objectsWithHierarchy.ForEach(obj => baseObject.Merge(obj, MergeSettings));
    return baseObject.ToString();
}

static JObject CreateHierarchy(Queue<string> pathLevels, JObject currentNode)
{
    if (pathLevels.Count == 0) return currentNode;

    var newNode = new JObject(new JProperty(pathLevels.Dequeue(), currentNode));
    return CreateHierarchy(pathLevels, newNode);
}
```

- `mappings`: The top-level field names must be unique that's why we could create a `Dictionary`

  - the key is the field name
  - the value is an object which contains `Path` and `MainContract`
- `objectsWithHierarchy`: This linq query does the heavy lifting

  - It iterates through the previous `Dictionary`
  - `entryLevels`: This splits the field name by underscore then skips the `root` and reverse the order

    - for example from `root_mottaker_adresse2` we will have `adresse2, mottaker`
  - `deflattened`: It calls a recursive function to create the hierarchy from the most inner to the most outer

    - It utilises a `Queue` to support greater depth than 2
- Finally we merge together the `JObject`s by taking their union

  - Please note that we could also use the first element of the `objectsWithHierarchy` as the `baseObject`

---

**UPDATE #1**

I've put together the following benchmark where the `Original` is your version and the `Alternative` is mine

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Versions>();
    }
}

[HtmlExporter]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.Monitoring, targetCount: 5)]
public class Versions
{
    string json;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void RunOriginal() => Original(json);

    [Benchmark()]
    public void RunAlternative() => Alternative(json);
   
    ...
}
```

With the above setup I've run this on the following machine:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026) [Darwin 19.6.0]
Intel Core i9-9980HK CPU 2.40GHz, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=7.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET 7.0.0 (7.0.22.51805), X64 RyuJIT AVX2  [AttachedDebugger]
  Job-FYODYN : .NET 7.0.0 (7.0.22.51805), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
```

The results are the following

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RunOriginal | 121.0 us | 200.8 us | 52.14 us | 121.77 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 31.78 KB | 1.00 |
| RunAlternative | 111.1 us | 333.5 us | 86.61 us | 70.54 us | 0.90 | 0.36 | 36.41 KB | 1.15 |

From the above results I can see the following:

- Mine mean execution time is around 10% faster
- Yours memory consumption is around 15% less

Comment: Thanks! Could you also please let me know "In what/which parameter this solution is more efficient than the one I shared"?

Comment: Let me put together a bechmark.net experiment to compare the two versions from execution time and memory consumption perspectives.

Comment: @PPB I've updated my post, please check it. I would say there is no significant different between the two versions.

Answer (score 1):

- a proper naming like `unstructured` and `structured` instead of `obj` and `finalObj` or any better name that would add a better readability.
- `nestedKeyProcessed` can be omitted, if initiated `tempObj = null` and replaced with `tempObj == null`.
- `Reverse()` would add extra cost to the operation, it can be omitted since you can do a loop on the keys reversely.
- `Count()` is expensive, you could reduce its costs if you stored the results outside the inner loop and reuse the stored value, also it can be omitted since you can omit `Reverse()` and uses `Length` of `Array`.
- `CreateJObject` and `CreateJObjectUsingJProperty` are unnecessary.
- `JsonMergeSettings` can be cached and reused instead of creating a new instance on each iteration.

**Revision Proposal**

```
private static readonly JsonMergeSettings _jsonMergeSettings = new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union };

public JObject RestructureJson(string jsonString)
{
    var unstructured = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

    var structured = new JObject();

    foreach (var item in unstructured)
    {       
        var keys = item.Key.Split('_');
        // keys[0] == root
        
        if (keys.Length == 2)
        {
            structured.Add(new JProperty(keys[1], item.Value));
        }
        else if (keys.Length > 2)
        {
            JObject? tempObj = null;
            
            // Reverse() replacement
            for (var x = keys.Length - 1; x != 0; x--)
            {
                tempObj = new JObject(new JProperty(keys[x], tempObj ?? item.Value));
            }

            structured.Merge(tempObj, _jsonMergeSettings);
        }
    }

    return structured.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is some benchmarks using `BenchmarkDotNet`, it would give you a better view on how it would perform in general basis. Though, environment, and resource will affect the overall performance as well, so your milage will vary.

Setup :

```
[SimpleJob]
[HtmlExporter]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class JsonRestructureBenchmark
{
    private static readonly JsonMergeSettings _jsonMergeSettings = new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union };
   
    private const char LevelSeparator = '_';

    private string json;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        json = File.ReadAllText("C:\\TempFolder\\unstructured.json");
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public string Original() => Original(json);

    [Benchmark()]
    public string Revised() => Revised(json);

    private string Revised(string jsonString)
    {
        var unstructured = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        var structured = new JObject();

        foreach (var item in unstructured)
        {
            var keys = item.Key.Split('_');

            if (keys.Length == 2)
            {
                structured.Add(new JProperty(keys[1], item.Value));
            }
            else if (keys.Length > 2)
            {
                JObject? tempObj = null;

                for (var x = keys.Length - 1; x != 0; x--)
                {                      
                    tempObj = new JObject(new JProperty(keys[x], tempObj ?? item.Value));
                }

                structured.Merge(tempObj, _jsonMergeSettings);
            }
        }
        
        return structured.ToString();
    }

    private string Original(string jsonString)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        JObject finalObj = new JObject();

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            var keys = item.Key.Replace("root_", "").Split('_').Reverse();
            bool nestedKeyProcessed = false;
            JObject tempObj = new JObject();
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                if (keys.Count() > 1 && !nestedKeyProcessed)
                {
                    tempObj = CreateJObject(key, item.Value);
                    nestedKeyProcessed = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (keys.Count() == 1)
                        finalObj.Add(new JProperty(key, item.Value));
                    else
                        tempObj = CreateJObjectUsingJProperty(key, tempObj);
                }
            }
            if (keys.Count() > 1)
                finalObj.Merge(tempObj, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union });
        }


        JObject CreateJObject(string key, JToken? data) => new JObject { { key, data } };

        JObject CreateJObjectUsingJProperty(string key, object? data) => new JObject(new JProperty(key, data));

        return finalObj.ToString();
    }

}
```

Results :

```ini
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=Windows 11 (10.0.22621.819)
Intel Core i7-8565U CPU 1.80GHz (Whiskey Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=7.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET 7.0.0 (7.0.22.51805), X64 RyuJIT AVX2  [AttachedDebugger]
  DefaultJob : .NET 7.0.0 (7.0.22.51805), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 21.49 μs | 0.429 μs | 0.985 μs | 1.00 | 0.00 | 7.5989 | - | 31.14 KB | 1.00 |
| Revised | 20.03 μs | 0.395 μs | 0.566 μs | 0.95 | 0.05 | 7.2632 | - | 29.73 KB | 0.95 |

As you can see in the results, the `Revised` version consumes less memory since we eliminated `Reverse()`. which would save between 1% to 7% on memory consumption.

If you see the `Mean`, you will also see some improvement there, this is because we eliminated the need of `Count()` and replacing it with `Length` and used the cached `_jsonMergeSettings`.

Comment: Thanks! Have you done bechmark.net experiment to compare?

Comment: @PPB while `BenchmarkDotNet` is an open-source library and anyone can use it, I did it anyway as requested ;). I hope this would help.